# REST based authoring facility

Tags: services, 8

I intend to use Drupal for a news portal. We have a strong system which is exposed as REST based services in J2EE. Does Drupal have a capability to consume already developed REST services as a template while authoring a web content and executing the same REST call and replacing the appropriate place holders on publishing ?

What are the modules I would require to develop the same?

E,g,

Use case 1 : let's say I want to publish the recent export stats of a region and list out outputs from a set of manufacturing companies, I should be able pull the company names (available as a REST service ) and continue authoring.

Use case 2: Manufacturing company details page. (Details are available as REST api)

Use case 3: On Clicking on a manufacturing company detail page. I should be able to post back the visits count against the company to an external analytic tool

Use case 4: Use multiple REST services in a page and authoring a content.

I reiterate, in no case I need Drupal to produce REST services, only consume REST services

Comment: In what format are you exposing your data? You could try to use  https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds module (maybe with Feeds JSONPath Parser https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_jsonpath_parser).

Comment: take a look at https://www.drupal.org/project/services